# Loop through subfolders and files using dynamic filename

Tags: excel, vba, loops, subdirectory

The code below loops through my subfolders and files to open up a file with a specific filename (either in the form "Daily Report dd-mm-yyyy DAY-END.xlsx" or "Weekly Report dd-mm-yyyy DAY-END.xlsx"), copy and paste the relevant data, and then close the workbook.

The filename is dynamic and based on my MASTER excel.

I am struggling to see the logic behind the order in which fso runs through the subfolders and files. Some files are missed based on their name (they don't have the same naming convention so aren't in date order) and I have to manually run the code again to look for the lastrow.

How do I Exit the subfolder loop IF the relevant file is found, redefine the  lastrow and filename, and then start the subfolder/CurrFile loop again based on the new filename? Ideally I want this to run until the filename contains today's date.

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()

Dim fso As Object 
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolders As Object
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim CurrFile As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim MASTERwb As Workbook
Dim MASTERws As Worksheet
Dim MASTER As String
MASTER = "MASTER Report.xlsm"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set MASTERwb = Workbooks(MASTER) 'define this workbook
Set MASTERws = MASTERwb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'define this worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(“\\....\”)
Set subfolders = folder.subfolders

'find the last filled row in column D
lastrow = MASTERws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

'set filename as the cell reference in column A of the first empty row
' (column A contains the exact filename corresponding to a certain date)
filename = MASTERws.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value

For Each subfolders In subfolders

    Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files

    For Each CurrFile In CurrFile
        If CurrFile.Name = filename Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & filename) 
            [code to copy and paste relevant data from file to MASTER]
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close workbook
        End If

        lastrow = MASTERws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'redefine lastrow 
        filename = MASTERws.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value 'redefine filename 

    Next

Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolders = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop specifications won't work well (or at all) because you're using the list object (`subfolders` and `CurrFile`) as both the list and the individual item. You should use `For Each folder In subfolders`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you could need to change the two loops as follows:

```
For Each folder In subfolders

    For Each CurrFile In subfolders.Files
        If CurrFile.Name = filename Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & filename)
            [code to copy and paste relevant data from file to MASTER]
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close workbook

            lastrow = MASTERws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'redefine lastrow
            filename = MASTERws.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value 'redefine filename
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

Next
```

but your wording is somehow vague and you may want to enhance it if what above doesn't solve your question

Comment: @edc94, any feedback?

Comment: I've tried the above and it's producing the error at the line 'For Each CurrFile In subfolders.Files' of "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Sorry it was harder to explain than I thought it would be... My original code works but I think it loops through the files opening in the order for example: "Weekly Report 02/03/2020", "Weekly Report 09/03/2020, "Daily Report 03/03/2020", "Daily Report 04/03/2020" (i.e. not in date order), which means if it want to find data from "Weekly Report 09/03/2020" it can't because the loop has already passed this point. So it seems to extract data from all the "Daily Report's" in one go, up until it gets to a "Weekly Report" where it can't find the file from the remaining files.

Comment: Which means I can extract all the data I want perfectly fine but I have to keep running the subroutine over and over every time it encounters a "Weekly Report".